# DDay.ICal with google calendar returning multiple occurances

Tags: c#, asp.net, icalendar, dday

I have an ics file from google (attached below) and when I open the same in outlook, it doesnt add any event on the date mentioned in the file "20120823". But in DDay.ICal dll I use for programatically fetching the calendar events, the dll returns me 730 events. Any idea??

I saw a link that said that DDay have resolved this google calendar issue but seems its still not resolved. Any hack to this available will help greatly.

ICS content

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20120823
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20120824
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20120824
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20120824
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20120823
DTSTAMP:20131031T111655Z
UID:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@google.com
CREATED:20120621T142631Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20120621T142631Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Test Summary
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Below code returns me 730 occurances

```
IList<Occurrence> occurrences = iCal.GetOccurrences(
                new iCalDateTime(2010, 1, 1, "US-Eastern"),
                new iCalDateTime(2016, 12, 31, "US-Eastern"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is basically with google calendar but DDay have incorporated the issue in the code and republished the new dlls @ http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/

Comment: In the `VEVENT` you posted I would expect 0 occurrences; could you please elaborate on what the issue with Google Calendar is?

Answer (score 0):

([Don't use dday.ical](http://rianjs.net/2016/07/dday-ical-is-now-ical-net); use [ical.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net). It contains many performance enhancements and bugfixes.)

Looks like you found a bug. [Which I fixed](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/issues/111), and [added a unit test](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/blob/master/ical.NET.UnitTests/RecurrenceTests.cs#L2876) for. It's [in ical.net version 2.2.8+](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net).